# Cannot use namespace 'xxx' as a value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having issues using the "FHIR" types library from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fhir

I have two different Angular application, one where this library has been installed (via npm) and added to the tsconfig.app.json file

```
"types": [
  "hammerjs",
  "fhir"
],
```

This application works fine and I can use constructs such as

```
orgData: fhir.Organization[] = [];
```

I have since created a second Angular app and tried to apply the same process where I install the types library, add the reference to tsconfig.app.json file

For this second app however, I get an error

```
Cannot use namespace 'fhir' as a value.
```

As far as I can see I have an identical setup as the first application, though clearly, I must have missed something as it does not work.

I note the question raised here [How do I use @types/fhir in angular cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661818/how-do-i-use-types-fhir-in-angular-cli-project)

but as I say I have one project working well and did not use the approach described there.

Any clues as to what I might be missing here?

The tsconfig.app.json file is as below

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom"],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "fhir"
    ],
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "pretty": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There are several tsconfig files by default in an Angular cli project. Any chance you updated a different one?

Comment: There are two  tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json - they are identical between the two projects

Comment: And a `tsconfig.json` in the root folder.

Comment: Actually, neither projects have a tsconfig.json file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I ran the YARN Install I did not have administrator privileges. Running it again with admin privileges fixed the problem.